# Using JRE 1.5, still maven says annotation not supported in -source 1.3

Tags: maven, java

I am using JRE 1.5. Still when I try to compile my code it fails by saying to use JRE 1.5 instead of 1.3

C:\temp\SpringExample>mvn -e  clean install
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringExample
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory C:\temp\SpringExample\target
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\temp\SpringExample\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
C:\temp\SpringExample\src\main\java\com\mkyong\stock\model\Stock.java:[45,9] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(try -source 1.5 to enable annotations)
        @Override

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
C:\temp\SpringExample\src\main\java\com\mkyong\stock\model\Stock.java:[45,9] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(try -source 1.5 to enable annotations)
        @Override

```
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
C:\temp\SpringExample\src\main\java\com\mkyong\stock\model\Stock.java:[45,9] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(try -source 1.5 to enable annotations)
        @Override

```
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
```

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Dec 22 10:04:53 IST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\temp\SpringExample>javac -version
javac 1.5.0_08
javac: no source files

Answer (score 7):

Do you have something similar to below to specify the java version to be used by the maven compiler plugin?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 5):

A shorter version

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
....
```